# How can I have the first element of a listview always visible when I scroll the listview?

Tags: qt, listview, qml

in my code i have a ListView of 16 elements, i want that when i scroll the listview the first element must be always visible. How i can do it ?

```
ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480


    ListView {
        id:listview
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: 16
        verticalLayoutDirection: ListView.BottomToTop
        delegate: Rectangle {
            height: listview.height/5
            width: listview.width
            color: Qt.rgba(Math.random(),Math.random(),Math.random(),1)
            Text {
               text: index
               anchors.fill: parent
               horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
               verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
               color: "white"
               font.pixelSize: 35
            }
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you could make use of a header. Your code will then look something like this:

```
ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480


    ListView {
        id:listview
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: 15
        verticalLayoutDirection: ListView.BottomToTop

        headerPositioning: ListView.OverlayHeader

        header: Rectangle {
            height: listview.height/5
            width: listview.width
            color: Qt.rgba(Math.random(),Math.random(),Math.random(),1)
            z:2
            Text {
               text: "0"
               anchors.fill: parent
               horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
               verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
               color: "white"
               font.pixelSize: 35
            }
        }

        delegate: Rectangle {
            height: listview.height/5
            width: listview.width
            color: Qt.rgba(Math.random(),Math.random(),Math.random(),1)
            Text {
               text: index+1
               anchors.fill: parent
               horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
               verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
               color: "white"
               font.pixelSize: 35
            }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: There's also [`ListView.PullBackHeader`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-listview.html#headerPositioning-prop) in case you want a header that is hidden while scrolling forward and visible when scrolling backwards.